# How to get rid of wierd blank stripe

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

Doens anyone know why my app has this white stripe on the top of my layout? im clueless...:/

my app use default bottom menu layout and this fragment alone (fragment_home.xml) looks ok(without white stripe). but once is placed in the in the activity_main.xml there is this adition white stripe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

finally solved...by removing some atr./ something something atribute which was there by mistake